# Excel VBA Diagonal Sorting

Tags: vba, excel

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCG5F.jpg)

Good day!
The image I attached contains the sorting I want for my data.
What is the VBA Code for this?

The code I use is:

```
For b = 1 To 30
    If a < 2 Then
        Cells(b, a).Value = 1
        a = a + 1
    Else
        Cells(b, a).Value = 1
        a = 1
    End If
Next b
```

It can only sort for 2 rows before it resets.
How do I expand it like the one in the image?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
For b = 1 To 30
   For a = 1 To 3
    If a = 1 Then
        Cells(b, a).Value = 1            
    Elseif a = 2 Then
        Cells(b, a).Value = 1

    Else 
        Cells(b, a).Value = 1            
    End If
   Next a
Next b
```